# What resources are availabe to improve my vanilla cleric archer?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric

I am in a relatively new campaign (level 5) and I just came into about 9k gold. I am a cleric and there is pretty much nothing I can buy that I haven't already. I have 12 str, so no more than a plus one on my composite long bow. I have a nice set of hide but low dexterity, so no more medium armor worth buying. I feel like enhancements are absolutely obscene in price, or so useless they don't do anything. I haven't found any useful magical items within my price range.

The worst part is, I feel absolutely useless in my group. My spells do virtually nothing, my bow cant hit anything because I CONSTANTLY role like Asmodeus himself is channeling his personal hatred towards me through my dice, and I don't have enough strength to be anything but a minor inconvenience to most melee enemies.

This is my character:

- Dwarf Cleric (no archetype)
- Str 12 Dex 15 Con 18 Int 12 Wis 20 Cha 10
- mostly focused on healing with the Healing and Good domains
- Channel Smite and Guided Hand as my two feats

  - breastplate armor and a composite(Str +1) longbow

I know I probably am missing something huge, but are there some things people could recommend for me to buy to be remotely helpful for my group?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Pathfinder 1e clerics are incredibly versatile and can be useful in many ways, depending on what kind of role you want to fulfill. There isn't a best answer to this question with the information given so far. Currently this question is very broad, and may get closed (until it is edited to be less broad). In the meantime feel free to ask users in [chat] for advice.

Comment: I recommend editing the question to be just a bit less ranty to something like *What kind of gear should my cleric buy?* Then just describe your character—and an overview of the party's composition. The site wants to help! Also, are the other PCs in the same spot as your PC or is your PC's situation unique? Finally, to be clear, a level 5 PC typically has 10,500 gp. To a total outsider, it sounds like this 9,000 gp windfall is the GM's way of compensating the PCs for a lack of treasure earlier; see [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/).

Comment: To that end - do any of the other party members have any magical items?

Comment: Also, it would be good to mention if there are any restrictions on what books you have access to, or if there are books that are specifically prohibited.

Comment: I edited for clarity and to hopefully draw in those better suited to answer it. I think there is *just enough* that we may be able to answer, but this could further be improved by including spells you typically prepare/cast, what the rest of your group is playing, and the role you want to fill with this character.

Comment: @Ifusaso I think you misidentified the issue at hand. I voted to leave this question closed -from review.

Comment: By "vanilla", do you mean "no archetypes" or "core manuals only"?

Comment: Despite this sitting at 4 reopen votes right now, I cannot, in good conscience, toss mine to join in. There's just too many details lacking. What are the source restrictions, is 3pp allowed, or Paizo only? Are custom magic items allowed? Why the terrible stat array for a self-proclaimed healing focused cleric? Also please, don't poorly format their responses in the question. Knowing their god would also be helpful since they have guided hand.

Comment: So here's a list of details we need to help you. As a cleric, we need to know your god. We also need to know what books are available to you to use. What is your typical spell load out? Why did you choose healing focus? *How* are you focusing on healing (none of your feats have any healing interaction)? What is your level 5 feat? You've only listed two, and you should have 3.

Answer (score 2):

Archery can be strong, but it requires feats.

There are very good feats available for a cleric’s spellcasting, but that spellcasting is so strong that they’re mostly just gravy.

So the usual answer for a cleric archer is to take archery feats, and let spellcasting carry itself. Choosing a domain to boost archery, if possible, is not a bad idea either.

In this, you aren’t doing too badly: Guided Hand is a strong enabling feat. Channel Smite is kind of poor unless you’re seeing a lot of undead, but it’s the right idea, and anyway you need it to take Guided Hand.

But you are missing the archery basics; it’s very hard to be much of an archer without Precise Shot, which requires Point-Blank Shot. And then you need Rapid Shot (also requires PBS), and after that you want to look into Deadly Aim, Clustered Shots, and Hammer the Gap if those are available. Improved Precise Shot is really nice too, though the requirements are prohibitive. That’s a lot of feats—even a fighter of your level couldn’t have all of them—but it’s where you want to work towards, and all of those are better than, say, Channel Smite. So that is a bit of a problem. Worse, since they require Dexterity, you can’t benefit from Guided Hand as much as you should, when otherwise you could dump Dexterity. Though you are not hurting for ability scores; yours are quite high.

Archery being as feat-hungry as it is, human becomes really valuable for the bonus one. A dwarf archer is kind of rough in that regard, especially at low levels where humans have 100% or 50% more feats than you. And then you are effectively “behind” two feats, having to get Guided Hand. So that is where a lot of your pain is coming from. But it will get better as you level. Speaking of, you should have another feat *now*.

Along similar lines, your domains are doing nothing much for you. *Holy lance* can be solid in the right campaign, but you don’t have it yet. Right now, Good doesn’t help you at all. And Healing is just a terrible domain, because healing is terrible in Pathfinder. The way to handle healing in Pathfinder is to buy cheap, low-level wands that you can use to heal **after** a fight, because none of the healing spells are worth even half a turn in combat until you get *heal* itself.

Ultimately, though, that isn’t the elephant in the room, which is this: you are getting to a level where, say, a magic weapon **is** required for archery, and you need a +2 enhancement to Wisdom, and really you should have had that *wand of cure light wounds* a while ago.

But now you have come into 9,000 gp, bringing you almost where your should have been (the game recommends 10,500 gp total wealth at your level). That can go a long way to fixing the problem—**if** you can get magic items. If not, those gold coins might as well be plastic for all the good they’ll do for your dwarf. “Wealth” is the sum total of your things’ *value*—if your things have no use, they have no value, and you have no wealth.

So the first thing is to figure out how you are getting a +1 enhancement on that longbow. How you are getting a *cloak of resistance +1* and a *headband of inspired wisdom +2*. Where the party can go to pool some coins together and get cheap a *wand of cure light wounds*. That is, in and out of character, your top priority. Your quest should be put on hold until you figure it out.

And take Point-Blank Shot, Rapid Shot, and Deadly Aim as you can. You should be able to start right now. They will help a lot. You probably need Precise Shot too, unfortunately, which sucks but oh well.

Anyway, if there is a wizard in the party, they should be casting *haste* now, which will help you, and in a couple levels you can do even better with *divine power*. And you’ll collect the feats you need. So things will get better.

Finally, even without magic items, you should not be missing all that much—you have pretty great stats. Your damage isn’t much, but the accuracy should be there. If you continue to miss, that may be a concern with the monsters the GM is picking out. Is everyone else missing too?

Comment: I don't feel like it's productive to simply point out all of the choices that could/should have been taken before. For instance, they obviously didn't envision this character as a human, so commenting that human would be better doesn't help this user. I'd recommend not removing them, but displacing them to a separate section (Section 1: how to work on this character; Section 2: general recommendations for others attempting a similar character)

Comment: @Ifusaso I feel that it goes to explain why they are finding this so frustrating, when cleric archers are commonly described as a strong idea. I feel that explaining why *those* archers work while *this* archer is struggling is important to the answer. And yes, I imagine a whole lot of cleric archers choose human because the feats are so direly needed. For a new player, it might be weird to think that choosing anything-but-human puts you “behind,” but in this case, it does! I think that’s important to this answer, as it is, and shouldn’t be relegated to a quasi-optional subsection.

Comment: I disagree; I think that's the perfect thing for its own section (instead of littered throughout a few paragraphs) but it is your answer, so I won't pester further.